# Create an Eclipse template to println a variable in scope

Tags: java, eclipse

In programming, I often have situations where I want to print a variable to the console.

```
int myVar = 23;
System.out.println("myVar" + myVar);
```

I'd like to automate the task by outsourcing it to an Eclipse template. So far, this is the template I have prepared:

```
System.out.println((NAME OF VAR IN QUOTES?) + ${var});
```

How would I put the name of `var` in a String?

Answer (score 9):

You are very close. It's just easy as that:

```
System.out.println("${var} " + ${var}); // quote creates the difference
```

Answer (score 3):

I use:

```
System.out.println("${var}:\t" + ${var});
```